# Are there anyways to make the StarterPack sends a tool to a specific player?

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a clicker to send my weapon from ServerStorage to StarterPack and it worked really good. The reason why i didn't send the tool to PlayerBackpack instead of StarterPack, this is because my combat, animation system are in the ServerScriptService. I sent it to Player Backpack but nothing worked. But i figured out that send the tool to the StarterPack will make all the players enable to receive it if they die. That will definitely be a big problem.

So, my question is: Are there anyways to make the StarterPack sends a tool to a specific player. example: in a tycoon game, if you claim that house, the clicker will send the tool to the player in that house, not the others.

If it is impossible, i will be very happy with any advices from you.

This is my clicker script if it is necessary..

```
local ClickDetector = script.Parent.ClickDetector
local canGiveGun = true


ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    local starterpack = game.StarterPack
    local MetalBatCombat = game.ServerStorage:FindFirstChild("MetalBatCombat")
    local batClone = MetalBatCombat:Clone()

    for i,v in pairs(starterpack:GetChildren()) do
        if v.Name == "MetalBatCombat" then
            canGiveGun = false
        end
    end

    if canGiveGun then
        batClone.Parent = starterpack
        local char = player.Character
        local human = char.Humanoid
        human.Health = 0
    end

    canGiveGun = true

end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the metal bat in `ReplicatedStorage` and clone it to the player's backpack:

```
local MetalBatCombat = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("MetalBatCombat")
--Code
MetalBatCombat:Clone().Parent = player.Backpack
```

This will ensure that only the player gets the metal bat.